# Escaping special characters & Encoding unsafe and reserved characters Lucene query syntax Azure Search

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have words "C&&K", "So`am`I" , "Ant||Man", "A*B==AB", "Ant+Man" in `index` of azure search.

According to [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/lucene-query-syntax-in-azure-search#bkmk_syntax) for Escaping special characters `+ - && || ! ( ) { } [ ] ^ " ~ * ? : \ /` I need to  prefixing them with backslash (\) And for unsafe and reserved characters need to encode them in URL.

for "C&&K" my search url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=C%5C%26%5C%26K~&queryType=full`

for "So`am`I" my search url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=So%5C%60am%5C%60I~&queryType=full`

for "Ant||Man" my search url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=A%5C*B%3D%3DAB~&queryType=full`

for "A*B==AB" my search url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=A%5C*B%3D%3DAB~&queryType=full`

for "Ant+Man" my search url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=Ant%5C%2BMan~&queryType=full`

For all off them I do not get search result. I get `"value": []`

for "C&&K" I have also tried

url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=C%5C%26%26K~&queryType=full`

url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=C%26%5C%26K~&queryType=full`

for "So`am`I" I have also tried

url => `/indexes/{index-name}/docs?api-version=2017-11-11&search=So%60am%60I~&queryType=full`

It does not work. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With standard analysis, all of these would be indexed as multiple terms. Fuzzy queries, however, are not analyzed, so it will attempt to find it as a single term. That is, when you index "Ant||Man", after analysis, you end up with the terms "ant" and "man" in the index. When you search for `Ant||Man`, it will analyze it in much the same way as at index time, but when searching for `Ant||Man~`, the query won't be analyzed, and since no terms like that exist in the index, you won't get any matches. Similarly, for "A*B==AB" you get the terms "b" and "ab" ("a" is a stop word with default analysis).

So, try the queries without the `~`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to femtoRgon's response, you may want to consider using a custom analyzer that does not index these as multiple terms if you would always like them to be searchable as they are.  There is [documentation on custom analyzers here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/custom-analyzers-in-azure-search), and you can use the [Analyze API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/test-analyzer) to test to make sure a given analyzer works as you expect.